# shortcuts lost after restart

Tags: 12.10, keyboard, shortcuts

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10.

When I try setting some shortcuts and restart the System they are "deactivated" or default (but they are still working). After one more restart they do not work any more. 
Can you tell me how to handle this problem, please?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please elaborate on how you set them and what you set.

Comment: You are probably experiencing this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1063617

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use as a workaround:
1) Install [ccsm](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager)
2) Open ccsm
3) Go to "Preferences" and "Export" your settings (save)
4) Go to "Preferences" > "Backend" and set it to "Flat-file configuration Backend".
5) Right click on Desktop and make a New Folder
6) Open the New Folder and navigate to /usr/bin
7) Open gnome-terminal from within the folder
8) Into terminal, run: `ccsm`
9) Go to "Preferences" and "Import" the settings saved on step "3"
10) Done.

[image]

Comment: Doing this seems to remove/clear/destroy *all* my settings. Not really a solution.

Comment: You will have to restore your previous saved settings. I have changed the answer to explain how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not using the flat-file. It will nuke your compiz settings so that you have to:

```
rm ~/.compiz-1 ~/.config/compiz-1
```

Instead try this workaround:

[Custom keyboard shortcuts are reset. How can I make them set permanently?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/229171/custom-keyboard-shortcuts-are-reset-how-can-i-make-them-set-permanently)