# Advantage of using GSettings over Flat File configuration in CompizConfig Settings Manager

Tags: unity, compiz, configuration, gsettings

The advanced tool to configure Compiz (CompizConfig Settings Manager - CCSM) can use two backends (2017):

ini = Flat File Configuration Backend
gsettings = GSettings Configuration Backend

You can choose the Backend opening CCSM and clicking in "Preferences" or editing the `~/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig/config` file.

Years ago Compiz would crash using some configurations and saving using GSettings Configuration Backend (but would not crash with the same configuration and Flat File Configuration Backend).

Besides of that, the GSettings Backend is the default in a new Ubuntu instalation (in contrast with others distros [(1)](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Compiz_configuration)).

Is there any advantage using one over the other?

Comment: Since `gsettings` is the cli frontend to  `dconf`, and `dconf` is in binary format, I'd say it should be preferred, but I might be missing something.

Comment: Thank you Jacob! But why a binary format would be preferred? Stability? Performance? Reliability? Certainly a flat file is easier to create and to repair.

Comment: Binary format reads and writes much faster (especially reads), especially when using in scripts in a loop for example. `dconf write` is much faster than `gsettings set` (lower level) but `gsettings` has a consistency check.

Comment: I am not sure if the setting you mention changes anything *at all*. It might be overruled by Unity. According to this: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Compiz_configuration#Configuration_backends, a settings file should be created: `~/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig/Default.ini`, but no matter what I choose, the file is not created, although `~/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig/config` mentions:  `backend = ini`. Unity seems to crash though. Many settings in ccsm involve managing Unity, so my "farmer's knowledge" would say moving them outside the dconf database would be impossible anyway.

Comment: Changing the backend preference via CCSM certainly made a difference for me (back in 2012) http://askubuntu.com/a/382212/12943

Comment: I tested it again and this bug persists: I can not use some shortcuts or plugins with GSettings backend (examples: "expo" and "put"). It works fine with Flat File.